# HTML - How to refresh Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I already created an Iframe and it's now working for me, the only problem is when I click the refresh icon that I've created in my Iframe, it does not work and I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null

Here is my code:

```js
function refreshIframe() {
  document.getElementById('iframeID').src = document.getElementById('iframeID').src;
}

function displayIframe() {
  document.getElementById("iframeID").innerHTML = "<iframe src='https://www.google.com/' height=\"100%\" width=\"100%\" ></iframe>";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="displayIframe()">Display</button>

<div id="iframeID">
  <div onclick="refreshIframe()">
    <img src="./refresh.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to happen is just refresh the iframe

Comment: Are you using a cross-domain url for the iframe? Can you trying removing the current iframe with new iframe

Answer (score 0):

You are trying - inside the frame page - to obtain an element that exists in the parent page. I already showed you how to reach into the parent to do things like this:

[HTML - Remove iframe Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841904/html-remove-iframe-display/60842086?noredirect=1#comment107661025_60842086)

Or, you can do

```
function refreshIframe() {
  window.location = window.location;
}
```